# Uniform convergence of exp integral

Tags: improper-integrals, uniform-convergence, uniform-integrability

I need to investigate a uniform convergence of the integral $I$ on E, where
$$
I = \int_0^{+\infty} x^2 e^{-a x^4} \, \text{d} x, \, E = (0, \infty).
$$
It's obvious for me that it converges uniformly on $E_{\beta}=(\beta, \infty), \beta > 0.$ I think on $E$ it converges, but not uniformly. How can I proof it?

Comment: The integral with $a=0$ is clearly divergent, hence how can you have uniform convergence over $\alpha\in(0,\infty)$?

Comment: We can't just say that $\alpha = 0$, because $0 \notin E$.

Comment: Assuming uniform convergence on $(0,+\infty)$, $$ \lim_{\alpha\to 0^+}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^2 e^{-\alpha x^2}\,dx = \lim_{\alpha\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4\alpha^{3/2}}$$ is finite. It is not, hence we cannot have uniform convergence on $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: It's not $\sqrt{\pi}$, but it's $\Gamma(3/4)$. But that does not a point. Thanks a lot! May you please suggest something there: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183841/uniform-convergence-of-improper-integral-6?noredirect=1#comment4492324_2183841

Comment: Okay, let it be from 1 to $\infty$. Still, what may you suggest?